# datasource going to null in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, data-binding, gridview

I have a gridview that I bind with the result of a linq query that's in a list. In my code behind, I then bind the gridview with the list

```
MyGrid.DataSource = MyList;
MyGrid.DataBind();
```

I also have the grid with sorting enabled:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="SortMyGrid">
```

In the code behind, I have the event handler set up like this:

```
protected void MyGrid(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    var NewDataSource = from d in MyList
                orderby e.SortExpression
                select d;
}
```

Now the problem is that MyList is null when the event handler takes over! I'm tracing it and I see it loaded fine, I see the gridview on the page with the correct data but as soon as I click a column header to sort the grid, the MyList goes to null! Why?? What's causing the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once your data is bound, the source is effectively "lost" on the next event. If you need to retain it, you can put it in your session and pull it out when you need it.

**EDIT** 
Well, the term 'lost' sounds harsh, but it is no longer referenced. Wherever you have a reference to it (page load, most likely), you can do this:

```
MyGrid.DataSource = MyList;
MyGrid.DataBind();
Session["MyList"] = MyList;
```

Then, in your event handler (when you need it again), pull it back out:

```
List<MyObjectType> MyList = Session["MyList"] as List<MyObjectType>;
```

where `List<MyObjectType>` is the type of your list. The `Session` is basically a Dictionary, which is why you can store anything in it, but you have to cast it on the way out.

Comment: really? Lost? How do I put the list in the session? Sorry, I'm new to the framework.

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification. What a drag!! I'm just wondering, are there any benefits for not preserving the value of variables after the page is rendered? Why is the framework built this way where variables need to be passed to another object instead of having the variables hold their value automatically

Comment: @frenchie: I am actually not sure why this is the case, but I know that it is true from experience :-). I suppose it removes the duplication of data; the act of databinding transforms the data into cell values in your grid, so once this is complete, it empties the DataSource property. This is just speculation though :-).

Comment: why is this solution working but it doesn't work for me? http://forums.asp.net/p/956540/1177923.aspx

Comment: I'm looking to implement the same thing but it's not working for me. The extraction of the data in the gridview to a datatable is not working. That's how I got the idea of reusing the initial list, which brought me here.

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void MyGrid(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
         var NewDataSource = from d in MyList
                     orderby e.SortExpression
                     select d;

          MyGrid.DataSource = NewDataSource;
          MyGrid.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that MyList is null.